# How will matrix $A^n$ affect the original eigenvector and eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For example, a matrix $A$ has three distinct eigenvalues and has 3 eigenvectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ corresponding to the three distinct eigenvalues.

So, am I right to say $A^4$ will result in eigenvalue^4 and the eigenvectors remain unchanged?

Comment: Yes. If $Av = \lambda v$, then $A^2 v = A(Av) = A(\lambda v) = \lambda A v = \lambda^2 v$. Prove the $n$th case by induction.

Comment: Yes. This is correct.

Comment: The edit obscured the meaning of the question, so I rolled back to the original.

Answer (score 0):

The claim that the eigenvectors remain unchanged can be interpreted in two different ways, one of which is true, while the other is false.

The first interpretation is

> If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^4$.

This claim is **true,** and easily verified:

If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then there exists a value $\lambda$ such that $Av=\lambda v$. But then $A^4v = A^3Av = A^3(\lambda v) = \lambda A^3v = A^2 A v = \ldots = \lambda^4 v$. Therefore $v$ is also an eigenvector of $A^4$, with the corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda^4$.

The second interpretation is:

> $v$ is an eigenvalue of $A^4$ iff $v$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

That claim is **false.** A simple counterexample is $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$. Up to a scalar factor, the only eigenvectors of this matrix are $\pmatrix{1\\0}$ and $\pmatrix{0\\1}$. But $A^4$ is the identity matrix, and *all* non-zero vectors are eigenvectors of the identity.

With the eigenvalues it is even more complicated, as here the claim may depend on whether you consider real or complex vector spaces/matrices.

For example, consider the matrix $A=\pmatrix{2&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0}$. In the real numbers, the only eigenvalue is $2$. But $A^4$ has eigenvalues $2^4=16$ and $1$.

On the other hand, in the complex numbers, this matrix has the additional eigenvalues $i$ and $-i$, whose fourth powers are, indeed, both $1$.

Comment: If the eigenvalues of A are distinct, then the matrix is similar to a diagonal matrx, whose diagonal entries are the eigenvalues of A. Thus if B is the m-th power of A then B is similar to a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the eigenvalues of B, but these are not necessarily distinct.

Comment: @P.Lawrence: While I indeed missed the distinct eigenvalues part, the conclusion of diagonalizability is still only true in the complex numbers. For example, I could pimp up my $3\times 3$ example to $5\times 5$ with additional distinct diagonal entries, and in the real numbers there would be three distinct eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors, and yet taking the fourth power would still add a completely unrelated eigenvalue from the rotational submatrix, which is not diagonalizable in the real numbers.

Comment: Suppose A is a real nxn matrix in which the algebraic multiplicity of each eigenvalue is equal to the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace. Then A is similar over the reals to a block- diagonal real matrix in which for each complex eigenvalue a+bi and its conjugate there is a 2x2 block with first row [a,-b] and second row [b,a]. If we abandon the requirement of the algebraic multiplicity being equal to the dimension of the eigenspace, then A is similar over the reals to a real matrix in block-Jordan form, i.e. a  matrix also having some 2x2 super-diagonal identity matrices.